# SQL - Check if data EXIST on another table too

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to check if L# exist in both table trkdriver and trkmechanic;

I created a procedure which will take in a L# but the issue is how do i check that L# exist in both trkdriver and trkmechanic.

```
execute v_emp(10001);
```

PLSQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure v_emp
(emp_license IN trkdriver.L#%TYPE) 
IS
result VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
select e# INTO result
from trkdriver where l#=emp_license;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RESULT' || result);
END;
/
```

SQL> select E# from trkdriver;

```
        E#
----------
         1
         3
         5
         7
         9
        11
        13
```

7 rows selected.

**I tried below to check if its exist on two tables:**

```
SQL> select E# from trkdriver where EXISTS (select * from trkmechanic where trkd
river.L# = trkmechanic.L#);
```

It give me 0 rows return..

```
SQL> desc trkdriver;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc trkmechanic;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 E#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(12)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 STATUS                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 EXPERIENCE                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select td.e# INTO result
from trkdriver td
join trkmechanic tm on tm.L#= td.L#
where rd.l#=emp_license;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  EXISTS 
    (SELECT A.L# 
       from trkdriver AS A 
          INNER JOIN
          trkmechanic AS B
          ON A.L#=B.L#
          WHERE A.L# = emp_license
    )
END
```